# executing ffmpeg command with getRuntime().exec() command

Tags: android, ffmpeg, exec

i want to run ffmepg command directly on android. 
a simple command

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 out.mp4
```

now the issue is that i have searched the internet and found the best android ffmpeg can be found here

http://bambuser.com/opensource

I have downloaded it and read the readme file and compiled it. the folder is ffmpeg. I have kept it in `<--projectfolder-->/ffmpeg/`

there is a ffmpeg executeable file in ffmpeg folder called ffmpeg folder

i have copied it in files folder and run this command

```
  try {    

    Toast.makeText(this, "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/com.koder.testffmpeg/files/ffmpeg -i /sdcard/vid.mp4 /sdcard/out.mp4");


    } catch (IOException e) {

    txt.setText(e.toString());

    Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

according to this link 
[How do I reduce the video size captured by the default camera using FFMPEG in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721759/how-do-i-reduce-the-video-size-captured-by-the-default-camera-using-ffmpeg-in-an)

but still it does not work always exception i dont know what is going wrong
can someone plz help me with this

```
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command:[/data/data/com.koder.testffmpeg/files/ffmpeg -i /sdcard/vid.mp4 /sdcard/out.mp4] Working Directory: null Environment:null
```

Comment: What exception you are getting? Please post the log details.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command:[/data/data/com.koder.testffmpeg/files/ffmpeg -i /sdcard/vid.mp4 /sdcard/out.mp4] Working Directory: null Environment:null

Comment: The problem is that your ffmpeg command is probably not really marked as *executable* in the android folder. Use "adb shell" to connect and then "ls -l /data/data/com.koder.testffmpeg/files/ffmpeg" to see if it is really exectuable

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?...I followed the same method and it is giving an IO exception. Can u please help me?

Comment: Same problem, could't find any solutions!!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `getBaseContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir` instead of `"/data/data/com.example.ffmpegnew/files/"`

Answer (score 1):

Give executable permission to `ffmpeg` like so:

```
chmod 700 ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
Process proc = null;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
proc = pb.command("String...yourCommand")
                    .redirectErrorStream(true).start();
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    proc.getInputStream()));
```

This code work for me for get system wakelock details in android.may be this will useful to you.

Comment: it did not work, gave lots of errors. how can i ffmpeg file in my project folder. and one more thing will this file be able to run on linux or not, becoz i have tried it and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You could combine above answers like this:

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 700 "+getBaseContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + "/ffmpeg ...");
```