# How to wrapper ffmpeg to convert video in c#

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I want convert video from .wmv to .mp4 in c#. I was search around google and the result is ffmpeg library. But i don't know use it in c#. Please show me solution or source demo for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of .NET wrapper libraries for ffmpeg. A quick search gives these results:

- [Video Converter for .NET](https://videoconverter.codeplex.com)
- [fflib.net](http://www.intuitive.sk/fflib/)
- [AVBlocks](http://www.avblocks.com/)

Another approach may be simply calling the ffmpeg executable from within your application and providing the proper command line arguments. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7350411/3618341)

Also, your question could be framed a bit better. Check out [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)